# choose lines from a file using a certain condition

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

I am newbie in Python and I need help:

I have a file with lines like these(see below). I want to copy lines from this file and since some lines have similar date, If lines have similar date I want to choose line with smallest value of the number ending the list.

```
'1990-01-01','f','2'
'1990-01-02','c','4'
'1990-01-01','j','2.5'
'1990-01-01','j','1.5'
'1990-01-02','b','3.9'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code first:

```
text_data = """'1990-01-01','f','2'
'1990-01-02','c','4'
'1990-01-01','j','2.5'
'1990-01-01','j','1.5'
'1990-01-02','b','3.9'
"""

import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby


temp = StringIO(text_data)
tabular = list(csv.reader(temp, quotechar="'"))
tabular.sort(key=lambda L: (L[0], float(L[2]))

for key, val in groupby(tabular, itemgetter(0)):
    print next(val) # or do something appropriate
```

I've put the text in the code and wrapped it in a StringIO object to emulate a file, but normally one would open the text using the csv.reader on a file using open().

Then the data is sorted by the data column (index 0), and the value column (index 2) - this sort order ensures that identical dates are together (I realise you mentioned 'similar', but this recipe can be adapted) and that for each date, the lowest value column appears first.

itertools.groupby() is used to iterate over keys that match certain criteria - where they meet that criteria, they are in the same "group". 'key' (what is being grouped on) will be the value of the date, and 'val' will be another iterable of available values within that key. Since only the first is required, using next(val) will return the result with the smallest value.

The output is:

```
['1990-01-01', 'j', '1.5']
['1990-01-02', 'b', '3.9']
```

Comment: I tried to apply this solution but since I read from the csv file row by row using for loop , I can't find a way to make a list of lists so that I can sort it. Would you show me how this would be if it was to read from a csv file?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand - the list is already sorted - could you be more specific please?

Comment: I tried to do: myInput=csv.reader(open(path)), then I read line by line: for line in myInput: tabular=list(line), from here i tried to sort using:tabular.sort(key=lambda L: (L[0], float(L[2])), and continued:for key, val in groupby(tabular, itemgetter(0)):
    print next(val)

Comment: I need a way to read all lines a put in list outside the for loop, and then sort it. when I do it inside a for loop it is tries to sort line by line I guess.

Comment: But the return result from the groupby iterator is already sorted by date and value... Or are you saying that one hasn't reached the groupby stage yet?

Comment: Sure. E-mail me at firstname first 3 letters of surname 'at' gmail.